# Group Data from text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with this repeated data

```
   UPDATE TGw_WaiService
      SET  inputVarClass = 'pp.ccc.conn.service.HJ22Var'
     where SERVICE='HJ22'

    UPDATE TGw_WaiService
      SET  inputVarClass = 'pp.cgd.wai.service.HJA5Var'
    where SERVICE='HJA5'

    (...)
```

I want to group all the information that is inside single quotes after the "SERVICE" assignment, in this case I want something like this

```
"HJ22"             
"HJA5"
```

I want to avoid to build some script in some programming language, how can I do it with some product out of the box, can I do it in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with Notepad++. Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   .+?where SERVICE='([A-Z0-9]+)'
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   $1\n
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression" and ". matches newline"
4. Then press "Replace All"

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eN3oK4).

Comment: You may simply do a Find All ... Notepad++ lists all the matches in a neat little interface.

Comment: PERFECT , can you explain me the $ sign in the replace section ?
and why we have to check the "matches newline"

Comment: @tt0686 a) `$1` is a special variable which holds the matching result of the 1st capture group (we have defined a capture group in our matching pattern with parentheses `([A-Z0-9]+)`). b) ". matches newline" means that the dot `.` which normally matches any character whatsoever, should also match new lines. In our case this is needed in order to match all previous lines. As a learning test, remove the option, run the regex and see what will happen! You can test it also at regex101 if you remove the `s` modifier (from the the `gms`).

Comment: Thanks very much one more time, you were quite enlightening :)